# How to get index of a nested json objects array state in react knowing one property value?

Tags: javascript, json, reactjs, state

My function works in vanilla but not in react with a state.
My state is an array of json objects.
I have a value from an object property and I want the index value from the array.

```
    var result = Object.keys(this.state.categories).find(key => {
      var tableau=this.state.categories[key].catID;
        if(tableau === val)
            return key;
    });
    return result;
}
```

I expect an integer but I don't have any error message.

Comment: *"My state is an array of json objects."* Almost certainly not, it's almost certainly an array of objects, not "json objects." JSON is a *textual notation* for data exchange. [(More here.)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2904181/157247) If you're dealing with JavaScript source code, and not dealing with a *string*, you're not dealing with JSON.

Comment: you can not get an integer value, because you find a key, which is always a string (or symbol). btw, your callback need to return `true` or `false`, but not a value, if that is not intended ...

Comment: @NinaScholz - With `Object.keys`, it will always be a string. It doesn't include Symbol-named properties in its array.

Answer (score 0):

> I expect an integer...

Two problems:

1. Your code uses `find` on the result of `Object.keys`, so what gets found will be a string, not an integer (or number), because `Object.keys` returns an array of the string-named properties of the object you call it on. (Objects can have properties name with strings or Symbols, but `Object.keys` ignores the Symbol-named ones.)
2. You're returning `key`, when you should return true or false. The return value of a `find` callback tells `find` whether to return the entry being visited, or keep looping looking for the item to return.

If `this.state.categories` is an array, you want `findIndex` without `Object.keys`:

```
var result = this.state.categories.findIndex(
    entry => entry.catID === val
);
```

Result will be the index of the first entry where `entry.catID === val` was true.

If you want the object for that `catID` rather than the index, you would use `find`, just not on `Object.keys`:

```
var result = this.state.categories.find(
    entry => entry.catID === val
);
```

`result` will be the first entry for which `entry.catID === val` was true.

Comment: @TJ Thank you very much, your answer is very clear.